# Function returning the index of largest value, skipping previously returned values

Tags: c++

I need to make a function in c++ that returns the index of the largest value. Whenever it is called it should skip the index it returned previously and return the index storing the next largest value.

for eg if : -

int a[8] = {2,6,4,12,5,7,12,8}

the function should return 3 then 6 then 7, 5,1,4,2,0

Edit :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int return_max_index(vector<int> valuebyweight, int n)
{
    int max_index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
      if(valuebyweight[i] >= valuebyweight[max_index])
       {
        max_index = i;
       }
     }

 return max_index;

}

double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values,int n) {
  double value = 0.0;

  vector<int> valuebyweight(n);

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {

      valuebyweight[i] = values[i] / weights[i];
  }


while(capacity!=0)

 {
    int max_index = return_max_index(valuebyweight, n);

    if(weights[max_index] <= capacity)
    {
        capacity -= weights[max_index];
        value += values[max_index];
    }

    else
    {
        value += (valuebyweight[max_index] * capacity);
        capacity = 0;
    }
 }
  return value;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int capacity;
  std::cin >> n >> capacity;
  vector<int> values(n);
  vector<int> weights(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];
  }

  double optimal_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values,n);

  std::cout.precision(10);
  std::cout << optimal_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Trying to implement Fractional Knapsack algorithm. If I run the code on input

3 50
60 20
100 50
120 30

it should give the answer 180 but it returns 200 instead because my 'return_max_index' function is returning the same index again (2) but I somehow want it to skip the index it returned previously (2) and return the index that has the next highest 'valuebyweight' i.e 0.

Comment: Please add to your question the code you have written so far, why exactly you are getting an error, and how it should function if correct.

Comment: You either need to remember each index already returned, or change the value at each found index to a number lower than anything else you may encounter.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen I just included the code that I was working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.I made some minor changes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int return_max_index(vector<int> valuebyweight, int n)
{
    int max_index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
      if(valuebyweight[i] >= valuebyweight[max_index])
       {
        max_index = i;
       }
     }
     //if all the values in valuebyweight are 0
     if(valuebyweight[max_index]==0)
     {
      return -1;
     }
     else
     return max_index;

}

double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values,int n) {
  double value = 0.0;

  vector<int> valuebyweight(n);

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {

      valuebyweight[i] = values[i] / weights[i];
  }


while(capacity!=0)

 {
    int max_index = return_max_index(valuebyweight, n);
    if(max_index==-1)
    {
     break;
    }
    if(weights[max_index] <= capacity)
    {
        capacity -= weights[max_index];
        value += values[max_index];
        // assign valuebyweight[max_index] to 0 as it already participated in optimal solution and need no longer to participate. 
        valuebyweight[max_index]=0;
    }

    else
    {
        value += (valuebyweight[max_index] * capacity);
        capacity = 0;
    }
 }
  return value;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int capacity;
  std::cin >> n >> capacity;
  vector<int> values(n);
  vector<int> weights(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];
  }

  double optimal_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values,n);

  std::cout.precision(10);
  std::cout << optimal_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to just keep the list of found indices in a static local.  But then, how do you know you haven't already seen this one before? So better to make it a class.  Then you can also do some optimization: sort the array once, then just pop the next highest index from the result whenever it's called:

```
struct mysort{
    const std::vector<int>& _tosort;
    mysort(const std::vector<int> tosort) : _tosort(tosort) {}
    bool operator()(int a, int b){ return _tosort[a] < _tosort[b]; }
}


class IndexFinder{
private:
    std::vector<int> sorted_indices;
    int invoked;
public:
    IndexFinder(const std::vector<int>& tosort) :
      sorted_indices(tosort.size()) {
        invoked = 0;
        for(size_t i=0; i<tosort.size(); ++i)
            sorted_indices[i] = i;
        std::stable_sort(sorted_indices.begin(), sorted_indices.end(),
                          mysort(tosort));
    }

    int IndexFinder::operator()(){
        return sorted_indices[invoked++];
    }
};
```

You should put in protections to IndexFinder::operator()() to handle what happens if the user calls it more times than there are indices in the vector.  As a bonus you should be pretty easily able to change it into a template class to sort things other than ints.

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty (it modifies the array), but gives an idea:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int index_of_largest(int array[], size_t len) {
  int r = INT_MIN;
  int d = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (array[i] > r) {
      d = i;
      r = array[i];
    }
  }
  if (r != INT_MIN) {
    array[d] = INT_MIN;
  }
  return d;
}

int main(){
  int a[8] = {2, 6, 4, 12, 5, 7, 12, 8};
  int len = (int)(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", index_of_largest(a, len));
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3
6
7
5
1
4
2
0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different than the previous answer @bloer gave, but shows somewhat of a shorter method (it still uses a class) by using C++ 11 (`std::iota` and usage if lambda in `std::sort`).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MaxIndex
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> index;

    public:
        MaxIndex(const std::vector<int>& tosort) : index(tosort.size()) 
        {
           // initialize the indices
           std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

           // sort the indices based on passed-in vector
           std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), [&](int n1, int n2)
                     { return tosort[n1] > tosort[n2];});
        }

        // return the nth highest index 
        int getNthMaxIndex(int n) const { return index[n]; }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> a = {2,6,4,12,5,7,12,8};
   MaxIndex mi(a);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
      cout << mi.getNthMaxIndex(i) << endl;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/GwyM77)

---

Second, is there a reason to consistently use `n` if you're going to use `std::vector`?  A `std::vector` knows its own size, so passing (and using) extraneous variables denoting the number of elements in a vector is inviting a bug to be introduced somewhere.  Just use the `std::vector::size()` function if you want to get the number of elements, or just pass the vector by itself.

In addition, you should be passing things like `std::vector` by either reference or const reference, depending on whether the passed-in vector will be changed or not.  Passing `std::vector` by value (as you're doing now) incurs an (unnecessary) copy.